# Segmentation fault when trying to delete window

Tags: c, linux, curses

I only need the `WINDOW` for the animation at the start and `main_menu` but after I get thru the `if` statement in `main_menu` that would delete win, I get segmentation fault and I just can't get rid of it. I want to delete it because when I try to clear it, the border and "Sneak" disappear, but "Play, Rules, Credits and Quit" stay on screen. Any idea on how to delete it properly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main_menu(int xm, int ym);
void rules(int xm, int ym);

int main(){
    initscr();
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);

    int xm, ym;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, ym, xm);
    WINDOW *win = newwin(ym/2, xm/2, ym/4, xm/4);
    
    box(win, 0, 0);
    mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 3,  xm/4 - 2, "Play");
    mvwprintw(win, ym/4,  xm/4 - 4, "Options");
    mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 3,  xm/4 - 2, "Quit");
    wrefresh(win);

    int anim = 2;
    int intro = 3;
    clock_t start_time;
    while(1){
        wclear(win);
        box(win, 0, 0);
        mvwprintw(win, 0, anim, "Snake");

        mvwprintw(win, ym/4, xm/4 - 5, "Loading...");
        wrefresh(win);

        start_time = clock();
        while(clock() < start_time + 30000){}

        if(intro == 3){
            if(anim < xm/2 - 7) anim++;
            else intro--;
        }
        if(intro == 2){
            if(anim > 2) anim--;
            else intro--;
        }
        if(intro == 1){
            if(anim < xm/4 - 2) anim++;
            else intro--;
        }
        if(intro == 0) break;
    }

    wborder(win, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ');
    wrefresh(win);
    delwin(win);
    main_menu(xm, ym);

    endwin();
    return 0;
}

void main_menu(int xm, int ym){
    WINDOW *win = newwin(ym/2, xm/2, ym/4, xm/4);
    wclear(win);
    box(win, 0, 0);
    
    mvwprintw(win, 0, xm/4 - 2, "Snake");
    wrefresh(win);

    keypad(win, TRUE);
    int selected = 1;
    int slider = 0;

    wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
    mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 4,  xm/4 - 2, "Play");
    wattroff(win, A_STANDOUT);
    mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 1,  xm/4 - 3, "Rules");
    mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 2,  xm/4 - 3, "Credits");
    mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 5,  xm/4 - 2, "Quit");
    while(1){
        slider = wgetch(win);
        
        if(slider == KEY_UP){
            if(selected != 1) selected--;
        }

        if(slider == KEY_DOWN){
            if(selected != 4) selected++;
        }

        if(slider == 10){
            wborder(win, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ');
            wrefresh(win);
            delwin(win);
            if(selected == 2) rules(xm, ym);
        }

        switch(selected){
            case 1:
                wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 4,  xm/4 - 2, "Play");
                wattroff(win, A_STANDOUT);
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 1,  xm/4 - 3, "Rules");
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 2,  xm/4 - 3, "Credits");
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 5,  xm/4 - 2, "Quit");
                break;
            case 2:
                wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 1,  xm/4 - 3, "Rules");
                wattroff(win, A_STANDOUT);
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 4,  xm/4 - 2, "Play");
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 2,  xm/4 - 3, "Credits");
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 5,  xm/4 - 2, "Quit");
                break;
            case 3:
                wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 2,  xm/4 - 3, "Credits");
                wattroff(win, A_STANDOUT);
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 4,  xm/4 - 2, "Play");
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 1,  xm/4 - 3, "Rules");
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 5,  xm/4 - 2, "Quit");
                break;
            case 4:
                wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 5,  xm/4 - 2, "Quit");
                wattroff(win, A_STANDOUT);
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 4,  xm/4 - 2, "Play");
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 1,  xm/4 - 3, "Rules");
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 2,  xm/4 - 3, "Credits");
                break;
            default:
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 4,  xm/4 - 2, "Play");
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 - 1,  xm/4 - 3, "Rules");
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 2,  xm/4 - 3, "Credits");
                mvwprintw(win, ym/4 + 3,  xm/4 - 2, "Quit");
                break;
        }

        wrefresh(win);
    }
}

void rules(int xm, int ym){
    clear();
    box(win, 0, 0);

    

    //   ─│╲╱
    refresh();
}
```

I would prefer to delete the window rather than clearing it, since I will only use it for `main_menu()` and maybe the main game.

Comment: Looks like `main_menu()` deletes the window it created when it reads a linefeed, but then continues to run and try to use the deleted window.

Comment: It should invoke the rules() function and not use main_menu() anymore no? If it keeps running after rules(), do I just add an empty return statement to it or what do you sugest I do? Oh yeah and please ignore the box() in rules, forgot to remove that but that isn't the problem anyway

Comment: Now that I look at it again, yeah you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window is deleted whenever the user presses the ENTER/RETURN key

```
if (slider == 10) {
    /* this section looks copy-pasted from `main` */
    wborder(win, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ');
    wrefresh(win);
    delwin(win); /* <----------- */

    if (selected == 2)
        rules(xm, ym);
}
```

Even if `selected` is `2`, `rules` will eventually return back to `main_menu` and execution will continue.

In any case, `win` is always used in the `switch` statement:

```
switch (selected) {
    case 1:
        wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
        /* ... */
```

This means you are operating on a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

---

For something straightforward, you may find it easier to manage each "scene" if they are clearly separate from one another.

Here's a cursory refactoring / outline:

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <string.h>

enum MENU_OPTIONS { MENU_PLAY, MENU_RULES, MENU_CREDITS, MENU_QUIT, MENU_LENGTH };
static const char *menu_entries[] = { "Play", "Rules", "Credits", "Quit" };

void print_list(WINDOW *w, const char **items, int length, int highlight,
        int y_origin, int x_origin, int spacing)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (highlight == i)
            wattron(w, A_STANDOUT);

        mvwprintw(w,
            y_origin - (spacing * length / 2) + (i * spacing),
            x_origin - strlen(items[i]) / 2,
            "%s", items[i]);

        if (highlight == i)
            wattroff(w, A_STANDOUT);
    }
}

int main_menu(int xm, int ym, int selected)
{
    WINDOW *win = newwin(ym/2, xm/2, ym/4, xm/4);
    keypad(win, TRUE);

    while (1) {
        werase(win);

        box(win, 0, 0);
        mvwprintw(win, 0, xm/4 - 2, "Snake");

        print_list(win, menu_entries, MENU_LENGTH,
                selected, ym / 4, xm / 4, 2);

        wrefresh(win);

        int input = wgetch(win);

        if (KEY_UP == input || 'w' == input) {
            if (selected != 0) selected--;
        }

        if (KEY_DOWN == input || 's' == input) {
            if (selected != 3) selected++;
        }

        if ('\n' == input || ' ' == input)
            break;
    }

    wclear(win);
    wrefresh(win);
    delwin(win);

    return selected;
}

void fake_loading(int xm, int ym)
{
    WINDOW *win = newwin(ym/2, xm/2, ym/4, xm/4);
    int anim = 2;
    int intro = 3;

    while (1) {
        werase(win);

        box(win, 0, 0);
        mvwprintw(win, 0, anim, "Snake");
        mvwprintw(win, ym/4, xm/4 - 5, "Loading...");

        wrefresh(win);

        napms(30);

        if (intro == 3) {
            if (anim < xm/2 - 7) anim++;
            else intro--;
        }

        if (intro == 2) {
            if(anim > 2) anim--;
            else intro--;
        }

        if (intro == 1) {
            if(anim < xm/4 - 2) anim++;
            else intro--;
        }

        if (intro == 0) break;
    }

    wclear(win);
    wrefresh(win);
    delwin(win);
}

void rules(int xm, int ym)
{
    WINDOW *win = newwin(3, 30, ym / 2 - 1, xm / 2 - 15);

    int wxm, wym;
    getmaxyx(win, wym, wxm);

    box(win, 0, 0);
    mvwprintw(win, 0, wxm / 2 - 6, "Snake - Rules");
    mvwprintw(win, 1, wxm / 2 - 5, "Eat stuff.");

    wrefresh(win);

    wgetch(win);

    wclear(win);
    wrefresh(win);
    delwin(win);
}

int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);

    int xm, ym;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, ym, xm);

    int running = 1;
    int last_sel = 0;

    fake_loading(xm, ym);

    while (running) {
        erase();

        last_sel = main_menu(xm, ym, last_sel);

        switch (last_sel) {
            case MENU_RULES:
                rules(xm, ym);
                break;
            case MENU_QUIT:
                running = 0;
                break;
        }

        refresh();
    }

    endwin();
}
```